# Does Avatar of Vice grant free uses of Dread Smite if I don't know it?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers, paladin

Assume I have a multi-class paladin, and have spent a feat to take Avatar of Vice (from Heroes of Shadow) as my level 29 daily power instead of whatever my class power was. The last part of this ability reads:

> If you start your turn with no uses available of your dread smite power, roll a d6.  On a 5 or 6, you regain one use of that power.

If I don't have the dread smite power to begin with, will I gain that power regardless with a 5 or a 6 on a d6 roll at the start of my turn?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short Answer: No.**

Only if you have the Dread Smite power does the d6 roll do anything. The power assumes you have Dread Smite. As you do not, you effectively stop reading the power.

Comment: The important part here is: "If you start your turn available of *your* dread smite power..." You don't have a dread smite power, so that section doesn't apply to you.